# Dropwizard - On deployment, application fails to run due to a malformed yml file

Tags: java, format, dropwizard, metrics

We are trying to add in automated metrics to our Java Application, with Dropwizard metrics.  So far, the config.yml file looks like this:

```
metrics:
  reporters:
  - type: log
    logger: metrics
    frequency: 5 minute
    includes: "io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-requests","io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-dispatches","io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-suspended"
```

When running this project, we get an error stating that the yaml file is malformed:

```
io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: test/config.yml has an error:
  * Malformed YAML at line: 24, column: 82; while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 20, column 5:
      - type: log
        ^
expected <block end>, but found FlowEntry
 in 'reader', line 23, column 81:
     ... tContextHandler.active-requests","io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableSer ...
                                         ^
```

What exactly is wrong with the way the yaml is written here?  My understanding is that the indentation, the spaces, and not having commas in within quotes were correct for this, and we're not able to find any other issues.

Comment: It seems that expressing a `Set` of values has other format: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/dcb1a7d9909397eefa4c18c659712f88b7559514/dropwizard-metrics/src/test/resources/yaml/metrics.yml#L8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change line 6 to

`includes: [io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-requests,io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-dispatches,io.dropwizard.jetty.MutableServletContextHandler.active-suspended]`